# Use absolute path in React components

Tags: javascript, webpack

How I can use absolute path from root and change root, for import components?

```
import Modal from project/app/src/Components/Modal
import Main from ../../../../Constants
```

and I want, change root directory to I can import from src

```
import Modal from Components/Modal
import Main from Constants
```

I try change workspaces in package.json

```
"workspaces": [
    "project/app/src/*"
]
```

or use

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_PATH=project/app/src/ webpack-dev-server"
}
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 4):

.env file with NODE_PATH=src is deprecating.

use jsconfig.json in root dir instead

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To implement absolute imports in create-react-app First you need to Create a `‘.env’` file at the root level (same level as package.json) then Set an environment variable, `‘NODE_PATH’` to `‘src/’`

```
NODE_PATH=src
```