# Absolute paths with parcel and react

Tags: reactjs, parceljs

I have a react app that uses parcel instead of webpack and I wanted to add absolute paths into the project so I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61228114/absolute-imports-react-and-typescript?noredirect=1&lq=1) guide and it works perfectly (you can `ctr click` on the path and it finds it(  BUT parcel is not happy with this because it cant resolve the path of the file if you say

`/components/thisComponent/thisComponent.jsx`

it says this instead

```
@parcel/resolver-default: Cannot load file '../../../thisComponent/thisComponent' in './src/thisComponent/thisComponent'.
 Did you mean '../../thisComponent/thisComponent'?
 Did you mean '../../../.thisComponents/thisComponents'?
```

is I tried using the `~` instead but that doesnt work as well. How can I use absolute paths with parcel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has worked for me:

```js
import {Button} from '../../../../../shared';

// changed to:
import {Button} from '~src/shared';
```

`jsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```